# override keys and vals

Tags: clojure, interface

given the type:

```
(defn as-pairs [m]
  (when-not (empty? m)
    (seq (persistent! (reduce (fn [s [k vs]]
                                (reduce (fn [s v] (conj! s (clojure.lang.MapEntry/create k v))) s vs))
                              (transient []) m)))))

(deftype Rel [m]
  clojure.lang.Seqable
  (seq [this] (as-pairs m))
  clojure.lang.ILookup
  (valAt [this k] (get m k))
  (valAt [this k default] (get m k default))
  clojure.lang.IPersistentMap
  (assoc [this k v] (Rel. (update m k #(conj (or % #{}) v))))
  (assocEx [this k v] (throw (Exception.)))
  (without [this k] (Rel. (dissoc m k))))

(defn relation [& pairs]
  (reduce (fn [r [k v]] (assoc r k v)) (Rel. (hash-map)) pairs))
```

Is it possible to *override* the calls to `(keys ...)` and `(vals ...)`?
As an example, the current implementation

```
>(def r (relation [1 2] [1 3] [2 4]))
> r
{1 3, 1 2, 2 4}
> (get r 1)
#{3 2}
> (seq r)
([1 3] [1 2] [2 4])
> (keys r)
(1 1 2)
> (vals r)
> (3 2 4)
```

For example I would like `keys` to return something more along the lines of `(seq (set (keys r))` i.e exclude duplicates. I can see that [in](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentMap.java)

```
static public class KeySeq extends ASeq{
    final ISeq seq;
    final Iterable iterable;

    static public KeySeq create(ISeq seq){
        if(seq == null)
            return null;
        return new KeySeq(seq, null);
    }
...
```

It seems that `keys` and `vals` is dependent on the implementation of `seq` for `clojure.lang.Seqable`. it just takes the first/second values from the `clojure.lang.MapEntry` pairs returned by `(seq r)`.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You might find the *Clojure Cookbook* article on[*Keeping Multiple Values for a Key*](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-22_multiple-values/2-22_multiple-values.asciidoc) interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to override this behavior of `clojure.core/keys` and `clojure.core/vals`. As you noted, those [Clojure functions](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1506-L1516) call the corresponding [static methods](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L595-L607) in `clojure.lang.RT`, which in turn call the [`createFromMap` static methods](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentMap.java#L135-L265) in the `KeySeq` and `ValSeq` classes of `clojure.lang.APersistentMap`. All these implementations use `IPersistentMap` directly to get their sequence, so they cannot be overridden independently of what you've already written.

One thing you could do in this case is provide your own `keys` function to replace the one from `clojure.core`:

```
(ns example.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [keys])
  (:require [clojure.core :as clj]))

(defn keys [m]
  (distinct (clj/keys m)))
```

Example:

```
(ns example.usage
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [keys])
  (:require [example.core :refer [keys]]))

(keys {:foo :bar :baz :qux})
;;=> (:foo :baz)
```

One thing to note is that it is part of the contract of `clojure.core/keys` to return a sequence that matches up with `seq`, so, for instance, `(= m (zipmap (keys m) (vals m)))` holds in general. This `example.core/keys` function satisfies that property for regular Clojure maps, but not for the multimaps you're defining. It's up to you to decide whether that tweak of semantics is a good idea or not.

Comment: sure, but I don't really see it as a solution... With this approach one might as well just forego the whole protocol/interface as a subset of functionality is only going to be useable by importing from the namespace which is obviously (to a certain extent) inconsistent. Makes little sense to have some things "built in" and others dependent on a `(:require ... :as )`. I don't mean this in a snarky way, purely a gripe I have with the actual language implementation. P.S you have been a champion with the weekend of answers!

Comment: @beoliver You ask such good questions, I can't help but answer them. I agree with you that it's not really a solution; that's why I didn't label it as such in my question. In my opinion, though, the language implementation isn't doing anything undesirable in this case; I would argue that a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) and a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) are two fundamentally different abstractions...

Comment: ... and so the reason you have run into difficulties in this and your previous question is because you are, in some sense, abusing the `IPersistentMap` interface. If I may make a suggestion, you might want to try creating your own protocol for the multimap abstraction, and have your type implement that rather than attempting to stretch Clojure's map abstraction. It's entirely up to you, though, of course.

Comment: I have one of those as well :P just commented it out for brevity! I mean the multimap is just `defaultdict(set)` in python ! which is a powerful tool. I agree that things have been abused! I think most of this started when I decided that I wanted to have the `(seq ,,,)` which seemed like a natural and desirable idea. As the `keys` and `vals` are a *side-effect* of that I thought it might be nice to at least control them. Most of this is trying to get an understanding of how clojure handles complexity (used in a very liberal sense).